# Login Activity with the help of Asyn-task in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout, android-asynctask

My problem is showing warning message while executing this task pls post the correct code for back ground process.

```
public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", editTextUsername.getText().toString()));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", editTextPassword.getText().toString()));
        String response = null;String res=null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Called for login server");
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("login.php", postParameters);
            System.out.println("connect");
            res=response.toString();
            res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return res;


    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(res.equals("success"))
            {
                Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainintent);
                finish();
                //error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
            }
            else
            {
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                editTextUsername.setText("");
                editTextPassword.setText("");
                editTextUsername.requestFocus();*/
                error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
09-24 09:07:54.894: W/System.err(4212): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-24 09:07:54.946: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
09-24 09:07:54.954: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:837)
09-24 09:07:54.954: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:54.964: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:54.964: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:54.984: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:54.984: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1440)
09-24 09:07:54.993: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:54.993: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:358)
09-24 09:07:55.014: W/System.err(4212):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15792)
09-24 09:07:55.014: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6524)
09-24 09:07:55.034: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3771)
09-24 09:07:55.034: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
09-24 09:07:55.054: W/System.err(4212):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
09-24 09:07:55.054: W/System.err(4212):     at com.loginpack.LoginActivity$loginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:111)
09-24 09:07:55.064: W/System.err(4212):     at com.loginpack.LoginActivity$loginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
09-24 09:07:55.084: W/System.err(4212):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-24 09:07:55.084: W/System.err(4212):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-24 09:07:55.104: W/System.err(4212):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-24 09:07:55.114: W/System.err(4212):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-24 09:07:55.134: W/System.err(4212):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-24 09:07:55.154: W/System.err(4212):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

After execution its moving to another activity but username and password wrong its not showing UI aft clicked in my screen only it is showing error login message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change with this..

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     if(result.equals("success"))
        {
            Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainintent);
            finish();
            //error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
        }
        else
        {
            /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editTextUsername.setText("");
            editTextPassword.setText("");
            editTextUsername.requestFocus();*/
            error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");

        }


    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

And this is Because you can't update your UI **doInBackground()** method.. you should use **onPostExecute()** method..

Comment: The way it is written, `onPostExecute()` doesn't have access to `res`, change it to `result` and you will have stolen the answer I was going to post ;) Also, suggest to change the params in the class declaration...look what `onPostExecute()` is suppose to be expecting.

Comment: in class declaration what should i change pls tell me?

Comment: @user2775674 The last param should be whatever `onPostExecute()` takes which is a `String`...you have `CustomHttpClient`

Comment: @user2775674 Then instead of returning `null` in `doInBackground()` you should `return res` to use this solution

Comment: but public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> is not working for me always showing incorrect username and password msg only displaying pls help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move any code that updates UI (such as `error.setText`) to within `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainintent);
            finish();
```

this code should be in onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

**`doInBackground()`** is a background non-UI thread and hence it does not have access to the layout defined in your application. So, any UI related code cannot be written inside it.

On the other hand, **`onPostExecute()`** is a UI thread is usually used to do the changes to the UI once the AsyncTask has finished.

**What you need to do :**

Define a flag in your AsyncTask Class and use it inside `doInBackground()` to set if it was successful or not. Then, inside `onPostEXecute()`, check the value of the flag and show the appropriate message.

Add **`boolean successFlag`** in your class definition.

Set the value of the flag in **`doInBackground()`**

```
doInBackground()
{
...

            if(res.equals("success"))
            {
             successFlag = true;
            }
            else
            {
             successFlag = false;
            }

...

}
```

Check the value of this flag in **`onPostExecute()`**.

```
onPostExecute()
{
     if(successFlag)
{
                Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainintent);
                finish();
}
      else
{
                error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
}
}
```

Comment: if(res.equals("success"))
    {
     Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(mainintent);
     finish();
     //error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
    }
    else
    {
     /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     editTextUsername.setText("");
     editTextPassword.setText("");
     editTextUsername.requestFocus();*/
     error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");

    } pls check this

Comment: No no. It is wrong. Dont use any Views inside `doInBackground()`. I added some code snippet. It should do your job.

Comment: I think some problem in my class declaration part pls check the code?

Comment: Why are you returning a CustomHttpClient ? Are you using it anywhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean variable in `doInBackground` true/false according to if/else condition, and check that in `onPostExecute` to start a new Intent or show Error Message

```
boolean isSuccess=false;

doInBackground(){
   if(res.equals("success"))
            {
              //do your work
              isSuccess=true;
            }
            else
            {
              //do your work
              isSuccess=false;

            }

}
```

In onPostExecute

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 if(isSuccess)
    {
        Intent mainintent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainintent);
        finish();

    }
    else
    {
        /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        editTextUsername.setText("");
        editTextPassword.setText("");
        editTextUsername.requestFocus();*/
        error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");

    }


pDialog.dismiss();
}
```